# Extract single index value (from every sub-array) from a multi-Key multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create an single-dimension array of 'id's' extracted from a multidimensional array that will **vary in depth**. I need to extract the value from EACH array (no matter how deep). Each array has been indexed (see below) with the same keys. I have tried flattening so I could use 'array_column' (doesn't work because of the number of keys in each array), as well as methods like print_r(array_keys($data[0])[0]) (doesn't work for unknown dimension depth). It seems simple enough but I'm not finding any examples that are like this. Any direction is appreciated. Thank you.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1000005
            [first_name] => James
            [last_name] => Smith
            [position_root] => CHF CUST EX
            [position_area] => Customer Operations
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1000134
                            [first_name] => Brandt
                            [last_name] => Jones
                            [position_root] => BS APL PJCTS
                            [position_area] => Customer Executive Support
                            [items] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1000149
                            [first_name] => Daniel
                            [last_name] => Brown
                            [position_root] => CUST PROG
                            [position_area] => CUSTOMER PROGRAMS
                            [items] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1000060
                                            [first_name] => Duane
                                            [last_name] => Pearson
                                            [position_root] => CUST PRG IN
                                            [position_area] => Customer Program Design
                                            [items] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )
```

What I am hoping for is:

```
[0] => 1000005
[1] => 1000134
[2] => 1000149
[3] => 1000060
```

... and so on ...

Comment: You might want to look into [`array_walk_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Comment: This looks promising. Thank you. I will just need to figure out how to isolate a single element ('id') from each array. I think I'm on the right track. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, you can use [`array_walk_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to achieve this.

```
<?php

$ids = [];
array_walk_recursive($data,function($value,$key) use (&$ids){
    if($key == 'id') $ids[] = $value;
});

print_r($ids);
```

Comment: @Nick and vivek_23 ... Worked like a charm! Thank you. Much appreciated!

Comment: Newbie question ... would I need to unset($value) and unset($key) after using this method? Thank you.

Comment: @Neil_Tinkerer Technically that shouldn't be the case because both variables scope is inside the callback itself.

Comment: Thank you. I had read that it was just a "good housekeeping" practice.

Comment: @Neil_Tinkerer Well, good housekeeping is more in terms of memory leak detection and prevention, closing unclosed mysqli connections etc. In this context, unsetting $value or $key is trivial. You can see in this link that throws a notice of undefined variable anyway. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fed91894d829c744ebded7795f2e871df8aa5d84

Comment: Wow! What a great tool you've provided. You are making the learning even more fun. Thanks for sharing this resource (and your thoughts on memory leak detection). Much appreciated.